# pass async value to method Angular 2+

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-forms

I have "onSubmit" method which return respond from server and method which triggered animation according to server response. Problem is "this.serverRespond" from "hideElementAnimation" not update value according to this.serverRespond from "onSubmit" method.

```
serverRespond: boolean = false;
```

animation function fire on submit button click

```
hideElementAnimation() {
  if(this.serverRespond) {
    this.state = (this.state === 'inactive' ? 'active' : 'inactive');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.animationDoneResult = false;
    },300);
  }
}
```

onSubmit fire on form submit and pass phone number from input

```
onSubmit(input_value): void {
this.smssend = this.service.smsSendRequest(user_phone)
  .subscribe( data => { 
    this.serverRespond = data;
  }); 
}
```

form

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(inputPhone.value)"
      *ngIf="animationDoneResult">
  <div class="input-holder">    
    <input #inputPhone>
      <button type="submit" 
              (click)="hideElementAnimation()"> 
      </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: you have a form that handles (ngSubmit) , why do you have a (click) added to your button with type submit?

also, can you specify your question?

Comment: sorry, i'm new at Angular2. Problem is "this.serverRespond" from "hideElementAnimation" not update value according to this.serverRespond from "onSubmit" method

Comment: So:
1. You submit the form.
2. You send a request.
3. You get a response -> Perform hideElementAnimation

Is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JanSomersJanS91 exactly

Comment: 1.remove the `(click)="hideElementAnimation()"`from your button 
2.add `this.hideElementAnimation()` to your request callback, right after `this.serverRespond = data;`

Also, Angular works great with data stream, and this is an example for which you would typically use observables and subjects (??!!??)

This is a video that helped me ENORMOUSLY: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYurQaN3RoE

Comment: @JanSomersJanS91 wow, this is so simple, thanks a lot for answer and video.